# Reordering JRadioButtons

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a matching style game in java that displays a group of thumbnails which expand into picture with 3 radio buttons, 1 correct and 2 incorrect.  Currently I have the 1st rb displaying the correct answer, it should be able to display on the second or 3rd but I can't figure out how to get it there.

So the possibilities would be (CII, ICI, or IIC)
(the rb text gets pulled from the filenames of the pictures)

```
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        add(textArea);

    JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton(rb1Text);
        add(rb1);
        rb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                textArea.setText("Correct");
            }
        });

    JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton(rb2Text);
        add(rb2);
        rb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                textArea.setText("Guess Again");
            }
        });


    JRadioButton rb3 = new JRadioButton(rb3Text);
        add(rb3);
        rb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                textArea.setText("Guess Again");
            }
        });

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(rb1);
    group.add(rb2);
    group.add(rb3);
```

Comment: Probably it's me, but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do or where you're stuck. If you need to change the text a JRadioButton displays, simply call `setText(...)` on it when and if you need to do this.

Comment: And if you need to randomize a number from 1 to 3, then use a `java.util.Random` obj, say in a variable named random, call `int randInt = random.nextInt(3);`, and then use that int to decide which JRadioButton gets which text. The JRadioButtons could be held in an array or ArrayList.... but again not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I've attempted randomizing the index and holding them in an arraylist, both with less than stellar success.  The reason I need this is; right now, the correct answer always shows up on the 1st radio button instead of a random button which makes the game pointless.

Comment: So.... now you know what to do, right? Or if not, at least show an attempt. Please consider creating and posting more code, specifically a [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org). This is a small but complete (i.e., compilable and runnable) program that only has code necessary to demonstrate your problem, again that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification, and that is posted here with your question and not in a link.

Comment: Just to amplify: we definitely don't want to see your whole program, and we don't want un-runnable snippets. Rather we want something in between. Please check the useful links above out for more details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out:  I changed the setBounds to include a one of the 3 desired y values pulled from a shuffled collection.

```
ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();

        obj.add("250");
        obj.add("300");
        obj.add("350");

        Collections.shuffle(obj);
        int rand1 = Integer.parseInt(obj.get(0));
        int rand2 = Integer.parseInt(obj.get(1));
        int rand3 = Integer.parseInt(obj.get(2));

        rb1.setBounds(400, rand1, 200, 15);
        rb2.setBounds(400, rand2, 200, 15);
        rb3.setBounds(400, rand3, 200, 15);
```

So every time the next or previous button is pressed it puts the correct answer in a different spot.

Thanks for the ideas Hovercraft Full Of Eels!

Comment: NO, no, no, not my idea. Never use `setBounds(...)` and `null` layout as that leads to terrible GUI's that can become very difficult to debug and enhance. Use the layout managers. Shoot JRadioButtons are begging to be placed into JPanels that use GridLayout -- don't disappoint them.